# How to show value if there any empty space in MySQL query value

Tags: php, mysql, database, radio-button

My database table is like this:

[image]

There are empty space in the field "pure math A2" in "course_name" column. I want to get course_name in a radio button value.

My mysql query was:

```
<?php
    $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_course WHERE label_id= 1");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
    {
    echo "<input type='radio' value='".$row['course_name']."' ".$class." name='vh_course_radio' >" .$row['course_name'];
    } 
?>
```

But there are some problems. In radio button, value is broken like this image:

[image]

Any body can help me? Please give me the solution. I want value will be like (value="pure math A2").

Comment: What do you mean "empty space?" Is the column NULL, or does it contain nothing but blank characters?

Comment: What value `$class` returns? It might return some value having single or double quote.

Comment: @OllieJones White space dude

Comment: view page source normally, debugger like your trying to rebuild input and you dont see what is really wrong

Comment: Please do not post code or DB structure as images. They are hard to read, and not searchable. Please add it as text in a code block instead. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use mysql `REPLACE()` or replace `' ' to '_'`

```
SELECT *,REPLACE(course_name,' ','_') as course_name 
FROM tbl_course WHERE label_id= 1
```

> Output is :- pure_math_A2

Comment: Thanks... Now It is working... I have another question, If there any single quotation mark like: A'levels Then how can I show it? can you solve it?

Comment: use this **select REPLACE(REPLACE("course's name",' ','_'),"'",'')**

Answer (score 1):

You are, I believe, hoping to insert a substitute value where a column value is missing.  There are two ways a value can appear to be missing from a column. One is when the column is NULL, and the other is when it's all spaces. You didn't say how your table records missing values, so I will offer a solution that handles both.

So, you can alter your SQL query to detect the situation.

```
IFNULL(course_name,'')
```

converts a NULL value to an empty string (no spaces).  Then

```
TRIM(IFNULL(course_name,''))
```

generates a text string containing no characters if the column value contains either blanks or NULL. Finally,

```
 CASE WHEN LENGTH(TRIM(IFNULL(course_name,''))) = 0 THEN 'substitute'
      ELSE                                               course_name
  END
```

will generate your substitute value. So use this SQL query

```
SELECT col, col, 
       CASE WHEN LENGTH(TRIM(IFNULL(course_name,''))) = 0 THEN 'substitute'
            ELSE                                               course_name
       END AS course_name
  FROM tbl_course
 WHERE label_id= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `replace` `space` to `"_"` (something else)

`<input type='radio' value='pure_math_A2'>pure math A2`

and in other side after submit you can `replace "_"` to `space` so your problem is solve

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
{
    echo "<input type='radio' value='".$row['course_name']."' ".$class." name='vh_course_radio' >" .$row['course_name'];
}
```

Use the below method it may help you,

```
<?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2)):  ?>
    <input type='radio' value="<?php echo $row['course_name'];?>" name=' vh_course_radio' ><?php echo $row['course_name']; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```